# two fixed point problem

Tags: numerical-methods, maple

The function $f$ given by $f(x)=x^{x - sin(x)}$ has a fixed point at 1 and another fixed point near 2.

If the I want to estimate fixed pt near 2 using a graph of the function, then:

[image]

This is what the function looks like the one. But my estimate is actually 1.0000 if x0=0.5 and by using the fixed point iteration code on Maple: FixedPointIteration(fixedpointiterator = f(x), x = .5, tolerance = 10^(-4), output = sequence, stoppingcriterion = function_value, maxiterations = 30).

So how can I actually estimate the fixed pt near 2 by using a graph of the function? The problem is that if I use x0=2 then Maple stops working.

Comment: Have you tried graphing the function and $g(x)=x$ on the interval $[1.5,2.5]$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Why is it important?

Comment: @AJR Look at your y-axis. Your functions blows up ridiculously large very quickly. Plotting to $x=10$ suppresses all the detail happening around the points you care about.

Comment: What does "fixed point" mean?

Comment: f(x)=x that's all. EVT is used to prove it.

Comment: I think I have to draw the $y=x$ on the graph and then estimate the fixed point.

Comment: You can certainly just plot y=x over that graph and see that there is a fixed point at x=1 and near x=2. But it isn't clear what level of accuracy you are looking for as this is just eyeballing the solution. The function is monotonically increasing, so you can just test points by bisecting the domain until the answer is sufficiently close to zero for your purposes. But I wouldn't consider that a very satisfying answer.

Comment: @J.W.Perry Thanks a lot. Now I really understand it well.

Comment: @AJR [:)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utpodw3ewf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reading that you want to identify values where $f(x)=x$ by visual inspection of the graph. I made [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xl0hlupshg) for you. You can zoom in to this graph and manually change  (play with) the numbers until they line up where you want, and to the visual precision desired, then zoom back out for the look I have shown here. With this method you can effectively get some pretty good approximations using **only** visual inspection of the graph.

In *Maple*, you will want to read documentation on aspect ratios. That may help.

Answer (score 1):

The standard error analysis (e.g. http://www-solar.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~alan/MT2003/Numerical/node11.html) indicates that fixed point iteration will *not* find the root $r \approx 1.93$, because the derivative $f'(r) \approx 2.73$ satisfies $\left| f'(r) \right| > 1$.

Other root-finding methods (e.g. bisection method, Newton's method, secant method) would likely work. The only caveat is that you should choose good initial values.

Answer (score 0):

As said in other comments and answers, the good candidate for this kind of problem is Newton iterative scheme. By inspection, you noticed that the second fixed point is close to $2$. Then let us make it our guess : $x_{old} = 2$ and define  $g(x)=x^{[x - sin(x)]- x}$

Now, apply Newton scheme which write
$x_{new} = x_{old} - \frac{f(x_{old})}{f'(x_{old})}$
Now the iterates are $1.94237$, $1.93469$, $1.93456$. At this point $g(x)=-0.00000555709$. You could continue iterating until you reach the required or desired level of accuracy.